# Running "Group By" Ordinal Counter Based on a "Flip" Column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

Usually I'm decent at set-based tsql problems.  But this one is beating me.
I've been working 3 days on converting a while-loop procedure into a setbased one.  I've gotten to the point below.......but can't make the final jump.

I have the following rows.  MyOrdinal will be "in order"  ... and a second column (MyMarker) will alternate between having a value and being null.  Whenever this "flip" occurs on MyMarker, I would like to increment a "group by" ordinal counter by one.  Whenever the "flip" values are non-null or null, these are grouped together as a set.

I've tried several things, but it was too ugly to post.  That and since moving to ORM, I don't spend as much time in the tsql anymore.

```
declare @Holder table (   MyOrdinal int not null , MyMarker int , MyGroupNumber int   )

INSERT INTO @Holder (MyOrdinal, MyMarker)
Select 1 , 1 
union all Select 2, 2
union all Select 3, null
union all Select 4, 3
union all Select 5, 4
union all Select 6, 5
union all Select 7, 6
union all Select 8, 7
union all Select 9, 8
union all Select 10, 9
union all Select 11, 10
union all Select 12, 11
union all Select 13, 12
union all Select 14, 13
union all Select 15, 14
union all Select 16, 15
union all Select 17, null
union all Select 18, null
union all Select 19, null
union all Select 20, 16
union all Select 21, 17
union all Select 22, 18
union all Select 23, null
union all Select 24, null
union all Select 25, 19
union all Select 26, 20
union all Select 27, null
union all Select 28, 21

Select * from @Holder
```

Desired Output

```
| MyOrdinal | MyMarker | MyGroupNumber |
|-----------|----------|---------------|
|         1 |        1 |             1 |
|         2 |        2 |             1 |
|         3 |    null  |             2 |
|         4 |        3 |             3 |
|         5 |        4 |             3 |
|         6 |        5 |             3 |
|         7 |        6 |             3 |
|         8 |        7 |             3 |
|         9 |        8 |             3 |
|        10 |        9 |             3 |
|        11 |       10 |             3 |
|        12 |       11 |             3 |
|        13 |       12 |             3 |
|        14 |       13 |             3 |
|        15 |       14 |             3 |
|        16 |       15 |             3 |
|        17 |    null  |             4 |
|        18 |    null  |             4 |
|        19 |    null  |             4 |
|        20 |       16 |             5 |
|        21 |       17 |             5 |
|        22 |       18 |             5 |
|        23 |    null  |             6 |
|        24 |    null  |             6 |
|        25 |       19 |             7 |
|        26 |       20 |             7 |
|        27 |    null  |             8 |
|        28 |       21 |             9 |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one:

First, this assigns a same `ROW_NUMBER` for continuous Non-`NULL` `MyMarker`. `ROW_NUMBER` is `NULL` for `NULL` `MyMarker`s. After that, you want to add a `ROW_NUMBER` for `NULL` `MyMarker`s such that the value is between the previous NON-`NULL` and the next NON-`NULL`. Then use `DENSE_RANK` to finally assign `MyGroupNumber`:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb/4998/0)

```
;WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT *,
        RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY MyOrdinal) - MyMarker + 1
    FROM @Holder
),
CteApply AS(
    SELECT
        t.MyOrdinal,
        t.MyMarker,
        MyGroupNumber = 
            CASE
                WHEN RN IS NULL THEN x.NewRN
                ELSE RN
            END
    FROM Cte t
    OUTER APPLY(
        SELECT TOP 1 RN * 1.1 AS NewRN
        FROM Cte
        WHERE 
            t.MyOrdinal > MyOrdinal
            AND MyMarker IS NOT NULL
        ORDER BY MyOrdinal DESC
    )x
)
SELECT 
    MyOrdinal,
    MyMarker,
    MyGroupNumber = DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY MyGroupNumber)
FROM CteApply
```

Answer (score 2):

For `Sql Server 2012`:

```
select *, sum(b) over(order by myordinal) 
from(select *,  
            case when (lag(mymarker) over(order by myordinal) is not null 
                   and mymarker is null) or 
                   (lag(mymarker) over(order by myordinal) is null 
                   and mymarker is not null)
            then 1 else 0 end as b
from @Holder) t
```

First you mark rows with 1 where there is a change from `null` to `not null` or from `not null` to `null`. Other columns are marked as 0. Then running sum of all rows till current.
Fiddle  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb/5015

For Sql Server 2008:

```
with cte1 as (select *,
case when (select max(enddate) from t ti
           where ti.ruleid = t.ruleid and ti.startdate < t.startdate) = startdate 
           then 0 else 1 end as b
from t),
cte2 as(select *, sum(b) over(partition by ruleid order by startdate) as s
from cte1)
select RuleID, 
       Name, 
       min(startdate), 
       case when count(*) = count(enddate) 
            then max(enddate) else null end from cte2
group by s, ruleid, name
```

Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4191d/6

Comment: I love the use of LAG here.....and wish I could use it.  My 2008 R2 requirement means I can't use this (this go around), but this goes into the bag of tricks.  Thanks.  Upvote.. but I will mark the other one as the answer because of the 2008 R2 requirement.